# how to get difference between two rows based on result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table like below

```
  ID  Value
   1   5
   2   6
   3   4
   4   3
   5   7
   6   6
   7   8
   8   9
```

output like difference between rows

```
  ID  Value difference
   1   5     null
   2   6     1  
   3   4     -2  
   4   3     -3   
   5   7      1    
   6   6     -1    
   7   8      1  
   8   9      -1
```

Scenario for above output:

```
1) id values difference
    1  5      1
    2  6
```

in above case difference >0 so we need to consider id 2,3 values to find difference

```
   id values difference
    2  6     -2
    3  4
```

in above case difference <=0 so we need to consider id 2,4 values to find difference

```
   id values difference
    2  6      -3
    4  3
```

in above case difference <=0 so we need to consider id 2,5 values to find difference

```
   id values difference
    2  6      1
    5  7
```

in above case difference >0 so we need to consider id 5,6 values to find difference

```
   id values difference
    5  7      -1
    6  6
```

in above case difference <=0 so we need to consider id 5,7 values to find difference

```
   id values difference
    5  7      1
    7  8
```

in above case difference >0 so we need to consider id 7,8 values to find difference

```
   id values difference
    7  8      -1
    8  9
```

Comment: do this client-side. the rules are ugly and will make for an incredibly ugly query.

Answer (score 0):

You should better do this in the programming environment where you capture the result set.
As you can see the SQL statement becomes a bit ugly otherwise, and performance could suffer from it as well when you have a large table:

```
select    a.id, a.value, (a.value - b.value) as diff
from      test as a
left join test as b
       on b.id = (select max(id) from test where id < a.id)
order by  a.id;
```

Here is [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6fd9b/2).

Outputs:

```
id value  diff
 1    5  (null)
 2    6    1
 3    4   -2
 4    3   -1
 5    7    4
 6    6   -1
 7    8    2
 8    9    1
```

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
  declare @t table (  ID int, Value int)
    insert into @t(id,value) values
       (1 ,  5),
       (2 ,  6),
       (3 ,  4),
       (4 ,  3),
       (5 ,  7),
       (6 ,  6),
       (7 ,  8),
       (8 ,  9)
       select id,value,value-n  as diff from @t t
 cross apply (select max(value) n from @t where id<t.id) t1
```

result

```
id  value   diff
1   5   NULL
2   6   1
3   4   -2
4   3   -3
5   7   1
6   6   -1
7   8   1
8   9   1
```